# Apple rejecting my app due to permission missing from Info.plist but my permissions are localized

Tags: ios, react-native

So I had my keys before in the `info.plist` file, but I wanted to localize them, which I did, so I created the `infoPlist.string` for english and spanish. They both work. But when I attempted to upload the build to the store, it sent me a rejecting email saying that the keys are missing from the `info.plist`. **I removed them from there since I had them `localized` now. How am I supposed to do it now?** **If I add them back into the Info.plist, it might take those as default?**

What should I do here?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You should still have the required strings in Info.plist as well as appropriate translations in the InfoPlist.strings file for each locale

Comment: Should I set the english ones there in the Info.plist then? Which one would be taken as default?

Comment: You can use English; The "default" will be taken from the base infoplist.strings file.

Comment: Nice, thanks man! you can post this answer and i will select it as correct.